# UIAlertView is showing up late

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services, uialertview

I am communicating with server in my ios app. I have following method in which I'm opening an  alertview. I want to show a loading view while app is getting response from the server.

```
- (void) showDetailedQuestion:(id)sender
{
       //loading view                  
        self.loading_alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Loading\nPlease Wait..." message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [self.loading_alert show];

        UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

        // Adjust the indicator so it is up a few pixels from the bottom of the alert
        indicator.center = CGPointMake(loading_alert.bounds.size.width / 2, loading_alert.bounds.size.height - 50);
        [indicator startAnimating];
        [self.loading_alert addSubview:indicator];

    UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender;
    int indx = btn.tag;

    NSLog(@"tag:%d",indx);
    answerAnQuestion *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Answer"];

    vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal ;
    vc.que_id = [self.que_id valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indx]];
    vc.qid_list = self.que_id;
    vc.crnt = indx;

    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
    [self.loading_alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
```

and in another answerAnQuestion.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
            NSString *address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@%@%@%@", path,@"questions/",que_id,@"?token=",token,@"&user_id=",usrId];
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:address];
    NSLog(@"%@",address);

    [NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[URL host]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowedInMemoryOnly
                                                       timeoutInterval:60.0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

    NSURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error]; 

    if (data) 
    {
        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;
        //If you need the response, you can use it here
        int statuscode = [httpResponse statusCode];
        NSString *responseMsg = [NSHTTPURLResponse localizedStringForStatusCode:statuscode];
        NSLog(@" Status code: %d",statuscode );
        NSLog(@" Status msg: %@",responseMsg );

    }
    else 
    {
        // Handle error by looking at response and/or error values
        NSLog(@"%@",error);
    }
}
```

My problem is alertview is only shown up for a moment when view is changing. It suppose to open when I click the button. What could be the reason? how to solve this?

EDIT 1:

If i make asynchronous request to server then i'm not able to set those data in my tableview. I can set those data in my tableview Only if send synchronous request,but it blocks the app. Why this is happening ?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: i think you facing similor prob as i give this answer take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17306039/ios-uialertview-show-immediately-before-for-loop-executes/17306225#17306225

Comment: The alert view can's show while the UI thread is tied up doing other stuff.  Doing, eg, a synchronous HTTP request in viewDidLoad prevents the UI thread from doing anything else.

Comment: Use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking), saves a lot of pain and makes handling issues like this easy (using blocks).

Comment: @NitinGohel  : i have tried your solution of Grand Central Dispatch (GCD). But same result. It showing up lately.

Comment: I can't make asynchronous requests as i'm updating my view from server's data.

Comment: Ah, that kind of problem is what separates the programmers from the wannabes.

Comment: (Hint: Display a "placeholder" in your view until the data is available.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending SynchronousRequest on main thread, so it is blocking your UI thread. Read multithreading you will get various tutorial on this. I can suggest you to go for GCD or NSOperation and NSOperationQueue. Google for any of the above and you will get various sample for the same.

Or you can send asynchronous request as follows...

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){
        //Write code you want to call when data is received,
        //Like dismissing loading view and populating UI.
 }];
```

Updated:

```
//Display alert view, before sending your request..
[alertview show];
//send first request
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request1 queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){

            //Write code you want to call when data is received,
            //send second request
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request2 queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){

            //Write code you want to call when data is received,
            //send third request
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request3 queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){
            //Write code you want to call when data is received,
            //dismiss alert view on main thread
dispatch_async(getmainqueue, ^(void) { 
// dismiss alert view... 
});
     }];
     }];

     }];
```

Comment: if i write my UIAlertView code in "dispatch_async(myBackgroundQueue, ^(void) {
    // my alertview code
});" will it work...?

Comment: actually i'm calling three url to get data from the server. i put all three of them  in block provided by you. will it work?

Comment: First thing you should not display alertview in myBackgroundQueue since it UI related and all UI related task should be performed in main thread.So first display your alert view on main thread then call above method to send request.How you want to send three request when one is completed?Check my updated code.

Comment: I tried your answer, alertview is coming up on time. but i'm unable set that server's response in uitableview.

Comment: After dismissing alert view, just reload your tableview, it will update the tableview. Call [yourTableView reloadData] after dismissing alert view, and keep break point in cellForRowAtIndexPath to cross check that your tableview reloading.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with Nuzhat Zari code, and I thank him for it, but also have experienced some issues with some core data operations between nested "sendAsynchronousRequest" (getting some weird thread and memory errors) so, my solution was unnest the calls to "sendAsynchronousRequest" and use some main thread variable validation.

```
@interface myMainThreadClass
@property (nonatomic,assign) NSInteger *currentAsyncTasks;
@end
@implementation

// Use init or viewDidLoad to make "currentAsyncTasks=0"!!

-(void)method
{
[self showLoadingAlert]; //or some ui update function

currentAsyncTasks++;
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){
    //do something with data
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
        [self dismissAlertInFinalTask] 
    });
}];
 currentAsyncTasks++;
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest2 queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){
    //do something with data 
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
        [self dismissAlertInFinalTask] 
    });
}];

 currentAsyncTasks++;
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest3 queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){

   //do something with data 
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
        [self dismissAlertInFinalTask] 
    });
}];
}
-(void)dismissAlertInFinalTask
{
    currentNetworkTasks--;
    if (currentNetworkTasks == 0)
    {
        [self dismissLoadingAlert];//or some ui update function;
    }
}
@end
```

I also want to know if someone has managed to do multiple request using NSURLConnection delegate NSURLConnectionDataDelegate and ui calls.